# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

Im kinda new at node and stack for a long time with this error. Please help me sovle my problem.
Here is my code:

```
app.get('/', function(req , res){
request(url, function(err, response, html){
if (!err && response.statusCode == 200){
  var page = cheerio.load(html);
  page('.search-result-description').each(function(){
    var data = [];
    var name = page(this).find('.search-result-item__head');
    var company = page(this).find('.search-result-item__company');
    var description = page(this).find('.search-result-item__snippet');
    var requirements = page(this).find('.search-result-item__snippet');
    var salary = page(this).find('.b-vacancy-list-salary');

    data.push({
      vac_name:  name.eq(0).text(),
      vac_description: description.eq(0).text(),
      vac_requirements: requirements.eq(0).text(),
      var_company: company.eq(0).text(),
      vac_salary : salary.eq(0).text()
    });
    data = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
    res.render('main.ejs', {data: data});
  });
  }
});
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Methods that send the http response like `res.render()` can only be called once per request (there's only one response per request).  When you call them more than once, you get the error message about headers already being sent.

Assuming your `page()` function is synchronous, you just need to move a couple statements after the end of the loop instead of inside the loop and move your declaration of the `data` variable outside the loop too so you can accumulate data with the loop:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    request(url, function(err, response, html) {
        if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var page = cheerio.load(html);
            var data = [];
            page('.search-result-description').each(function() {
                var name = page(this).find('.search-result-item__head');
                var company = page(this).find('.search-result-item__company');
                var description = page(this).find('.search-result-item__snippet');
                var requirements = page(this).find('.search-result-item__snippet');
                var salary = page(this).find('.b-vacancy-list-salary');

                data.push({
                    vac_name: name.eq(0).text(),
                    vac_description: description.eq(0).text(),
                    vac_requirements: requirements.eq(0).text(),
                    var_company: company.eq(0).text(),
                    vac_salary: salary.eq(0).text()
                });
            });
            res.render('main.ejs', {
               data: JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You also should have some error handling if the `request()` operation returns an error.  As it stands how, you just never respond to the request.

Answer (score 6):

In express, the method render(), send(), json() can invoke one time to response to the client, the second invoke will emit Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. From your code, res.render() was invoked many times, because you call it inside a loop. It's better if you check if response is finish or not before invoke render(), or rework your logic to call render() only one.

Comment: This is an appropriate answer as this issue is more like a "keep in mind" thing!

Answer (score 1):

Add the line `return false` after `res.render`

Answer (score 0):

Also when sending multiple responses in different if-else blocks or using callbacks, be sure to return null after setting a response.

let update = function (req, res, next) {

```
    let authResponse = res;
    console.log('userData==> ', req.body.userData)
    if (!req.params.ID) {
        console.log(':: res 1')
        res.status(404).json({
            status: 'failed',
            data: 'user id not defined'
        });
        return null;
    }
```

}

this stops the setting of repsonses and doesn't make the execution go further. so you can't set multiple res headers. not related directly, but just another case where you can get this kind of issue.